# Cannot run snap app

Tags: 16.04, permissions, snap

I have successfully installed snapd on Ubuntu 16.04 but while running the app, say `snap run hello` I am getting the following error:

**cannot create lock directory /run/snapd/lock: Permission denied**

I have tried the following

```
sudo apparmor_parser --replace --write-cache /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real --cache-loc /etc/apparmor.d/cache
```

but did not work even after restart. I am not able to run any snap app though able to install any apps.

The snapd service is also running. But still even after reboot, the problem remains the same.

Comment: Snapd is pre-installed on 16.04. The fact you installed it and it doesn't work suggests you are running a non standard build of Ubuntu with a non-ubuntu kernel. What's the output of 'snap version'

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you to try reinstalling the package hello and then run:

```
sudo snap run hello
```

If this does not work, you should try reinstalling Snap and refreshing the snap core using:

```
sudo snap refresh core
```

Comment: `sudo snap run app_name` work for me

Comment: hi, I installed cmake using snap. So I can run 'snap run cmake' but not just 'cmake'. Many install scripts are provided to use command 'cmake'. So I made an alias (alias cmake='snap run cmake'). Is this the way people use applications installed by snap?